# Strange output using Atomic Integer in Producer Consumer Problem in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomicinteger

While implementing Producer-Consumer Problem in Java using BlockingQueue, getting strange output using AtomicInteger, where 2 threads are producing the same result and putting the same counter variable in the queue. How are that output possible considering compare and swap technique used by Atomic Integer?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ProducerConsumer {
    static BlockingQueue<Integer> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(25);
    static AtomicInteger counter=new AtomicInteger(0);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Runnable producer = () -> {
          while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
              try {
                  final int e = counter.incrementAndGet();
                  queue.put(e);
                  if(e==26){
                      System.out.println("this is breaking the sequence...., value 26");
                  }
                   // System.out.println("Producer has produced the data:" +e);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
        };

        ExecutorService producerPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(25);
        for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
            producerPool.submit(producer);
        }

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Scanner scanInput= new Scanner(System.in);
        if(scanInput.next() != null){
            producerPool.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

}
```

it produces the output as below, where counter reached 26

```
this is breaking the sequence...., value 26
```

Can produce below result as well in different run : where counter reaches upto 25 only which is correct

```
no output
```

I know I am not using any synchronization for updating the counter value and put it in the queue, which will fix the issue with a sequence output, but my concern is understanding the Atomic Integer working, and how it is not suitable in this scenario.
Any thoughts on this behavior. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now you're printing the `AtomicInteger` value using its `toString` method

```
"Producer has produced the data:" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + counter
```

You need to extract the `AtomicInteger` value

```
final int e = counter.incrementAndGet();
queue.put(e);
System.out.println("Producer has produced the data:" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + e);
```

If you do no extract it before, at the time of the `toString` call the value could have been updated by another thread. It won't be *atomic* anymore.

Comment: Decrementing the value code is commented out, and it does not run. I just put it there as part of Producer Consumer problem. Here we are interested only in first part where producer is simply producing the data and place it in queue. I have removed the consumer code to avoid confusion. thanks

Comment: yes, it does solve the issue. but how does it getting the value via toString() method ? so always use the return value instead of directly referring the global reference

Comment: @RohitNarang you were passing the counter variable to the System.out.println, thus its toString method gets called. As per edit, that is not an atomic operation anymore.

Comment: @RohitNarang sorry for the initial misunderstanding. I'm on the phone and didn't read well.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again.  ` final int e = counter.incrementAndGet();
                  queue.put(e);
                  if(e==7){
                      System.out.println("this is breaking the sequence....");
                  } `  this is actually going into if condition where e being 7. I am avoiding print out now.

Comment: @RohitNarang it should still work correctly, right? The `counter` will be `7` only once

Comment: unfortunately not, used the same thing as suggested by you, just added if condition for value if ever equal to 7, once in a while, you can notice if goes inside if clock where value was 7..

Comment: Actually i notice value as 7 in previous solution thats why added a check.

Comment: @RohitNarang could you update the question with the current code?

Comment: i got that, its a race condition where incrementing and putting into the queue is not atomic

Comment: @RohitNarang I'm trying the code out. I don't understand what's the issue, I mean, does the number gets printed multiple times?

Comment: @RohitNarang oh yes, it's not an atomic operation, the Queue uses its own ReentrantLock.

Comment: it was like last number was missed in sequence in our case, so suppose a scenario where one threads which is at value 24 increments the value to 25 but not able to put it into queue, and in betwwen one thread reads the value as 25 and increments to 26 and put into queue successfully. so in this we have missed 25 number in sequence, last one is rejected and blocked because of capacity reached.

Comment: @RohitNarang yeah, you'd need to increment the queue capacity in that specific case, but it can still be an undefined behavior because it depends on how each thread behaves. Usually the queue insertion and removal are handled by only two threads to avoid synchronization issues.